# c++ auto keyword and function?

Tags: c++, auto

In the sha256 cpp code, there are some lines confused me:

```
 // Compress
auto RND = [&](u32 a, u32 b, u32 c, u32& d, u32 e, u32 f, u32 g, u32& h, u32 i)
{
    t0 = h + Sigma1(e) + Ch(e, f, g) + K[i] + W[i];
    t1 = Sigma0(a) + Maj(a, b, c);
    d += t0;
    h  = t0 + t1;
};
```

What does the code means after the **auto RND**, is it a function or something else? if it's a function, how to call it?

Comment: This is a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: `RND` is a lambda (note the bit after the equals starting with `[&]...`) and it's type is only know to the compiler.  `auto` is used here to infer the type (of the lambda).

Comment: I dont know why this question is getting so much downvotes. Even guys who has written C++ years before would see C++11 (or C++14), they'll find themselves in the same shoes! That actually says how much the language has changed, and for the better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RND`is a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) taking 9 arguments. As lambda function type are `unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type`, `auto` is mandatory or you have to use a type that accept lambda by copy/assignment like `std::function<...>`.

Otherwise, to invoke it, just call:

```
RND(......);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a function - it's a "lambda" function (despite there not being a "λ" in sight).

You call it like this:

```
RND(x,y,z,w,i,j,k,l,m);
```

Answer (score 1):

`auto` to infer the function type from `return` (no return then void), `[&]` all variables captured by reference, `(u32 a, ...)` unsigned int32 variables declaration, `{...};` body of the function. and you call it like `RND(...);` you could assign it to a variable if it returns a value...

Thank you, I just learn this trying to answer your question, so if some one see I'm missing things or there is more to it, please add.

Comment: `auto` in this case refers to the type of `RND`, not the return type of `RND`, which your answer seems to say. Were `RND` a function rather than a lambda (i.e. `auto RND(...) {...}` rather than `auto RND = [&](...) {...};`) then you would be correct.